# Applying dplyr::filter to a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse, lapply

I need to filter a list of data frames, using `dplyr::filter`. It should be easy, but somehow it does not work. List of data frames is `dflist`, basis for filter is value of `id`variable that should be included in `include_vector` (filter out those rows where `id`is not in the `include_vector`).

```
lapply(dflist, function(x){dplyr::filter(x, id %!in% include_vector)})
```

The function sort of works (goes through `dflist` and no error messages), but if I look at the data.frames after  the filtering is finished, the data.frames are exactly the same. What could be the problem?

Comment: try `lapply(dflist, function(x){dplyr::filter(x, !(id %in% include_vector))})`

Comment: you have a typo in your code: the `!`operator is at the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused as of what `lapply` does. It does not change the original `data.frames` but only in the list.

See this toy example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(id = letters[4:10])

dflist <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)
include_vector <- c("d", "e", "f")

new_list <- lapply(dflist, function(x) dplyr::filter(x, ! id %in% include_vector))
```

Now `new_list` looks like this:

```
$df1
  id
1  a
2  b
3  c

$df2
  id
1  g
2  h
3  i
4  j
```

But `df1` and `df2` have not changed. If you want to change `df1` and `df2` as well you can do this:

```
list2env(new_list, environment())
```

This will overwrite both `df1` and `df2` in you current working environment.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this.
However, I now get an error message after applying `list2env(new_list, environment())` command:
`Error in list2env(newlist, environment()) : names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x`. What is it about?

Comment: does your list have names? You can check by typing `names(dflist)`. `list2env` will only work for named lists.

Comment: No, it did not, but I fixed it by using `tibble::lst` instead of `list`. Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Using `purrr` and the same test data as [Cettt](http://user:5436877) (thanks!):

```
purrr::map(dflist, ~ dplyr::filter(., !(id %in% include_vector)))
```